# Trying to access properties of an object nested in an array returns 'Cannot read properties of undefined', what can I change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, fetch-api

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Representatives from './Representatives'

export default function Searchbar () {

    const [departement, setDepartement] = useState([]);
    const [representative, setRepresentative] = useState([]);
    const url = `https://geo.api.gouv.fr/departements?nom=${departement}&limit=1`;



    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchGeoData = async () =>{
            const response = await fetch(url);
    
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data);
    
           if(data[0]) {
            setRepresentative(data)
           }
        }
        fetchGeoData();
    }, [departement]);
    
    


    return(
        <>
            <form departement={departement} setDepartement={setDepartement}>
                <input type='text' placeholder="departement" onChange={(event)=> setDepartement(event.target.value)} autoFocus ></input>
            </form>
            <Representatives  representative={representative} />
        </>
    )
}
```

When I try to display data from the API, I get this error:

> 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nom')'

I tried to access object properties of nested arrays in other projects and I always have a problem accessing it.

```
import React from "react";

export default function Representatives(props){
    return(
        <>
            {props.representative.map(elu => 
                <h2>nome de l'elu: {elu[0].nom}</h2>
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you dont need to use [0] after `{elu`, `elu` object returned by map from api is not array-like.

That is your `props.representative`:

```
[
    {
        "nom": "Territoire de Belfort",
        "code": "90",
        "codeRegion": "27",
        "_score": 0.3556145506116622
    }
]
```

And that is the result of .map, `elu` object

```
{
  "nom": "Territoire de Belfort",
  "code": "90",
  "codeRegion": "27",
  "_score": 0.3556145506116622
}
```

So it will be (asuming `code` is unique, needed for `key` property)

```
function Representatives(props) {
  return (
    <>
      {props.representative.map((elu) => (
        <h2 key={elu.code}>nome de l'elu: {elu.nom}</h2>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```